# Azure Active Directory - graphrbac.GroupsClient#List: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403

Tags: azure, terraform

My service principal attempts to read a certain AD group using the following terraform code:

```
data "azuread_group" "hosting_ad_group" {
  name = local.hosting_ad_group_name
}
```

According to the documentation at https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/azuread/d/group.html:

> NOTE: If you're authenticating using a Service Principal then it must
>   have permissions to Read directory data within the Windows Azure
>   Active Directory API.

And indeed my SP has this permission:
[image]

Yet when I am running terraform apply as this SP I get the following:

```
Error: Error finding Azure AD Group with display name "AdminRole-Product-DFDevelopmentOps": Error listing Azure AD Groups for filter "displayName eq 'AdminRole-Product-DFDevelopmentOps'": graphrbac.GroupsClient#List: Failure responding to request: StatusCode=403 -- Original Error: autorest/azure: Service returned an error. Status=403 Code="Unknown" Message="Unknown service error" Details=[{"odata.error":{"code":"Authorization_RequestDenied","date":"2020-02-09T13:59:32","message":{"lang":"en","value":"Insufficient privileges to complete the operation."},"requestId":"b4f52aca-7306-4d12-95c9-cf922ae59483"}}]
```

What am I missing?

**EDIT 1**

This is how I set the API permissions from terraform:

```
resource "azuread_application" "app" {
  name = local.ctx.HostingAppName

  # AAD Graph API   
  required_resource_access {
    resource_app_id = "00000002-0000-0000-c000-000000000000"

    # Sign in and read user profile
    resource_access {
      id   = "311a71cc-e848-46a1-bdf8-97ff7156d8e6"
      type = "Scope"
    }

    # Manage apps that this app creates or owns
    resource_access {
      id   = "824c81eb-e3f8-4ee6-8f6d-de7f50d565b7"
      type = "Role"
    }

    # Read directory data
    resource_access {
      id   = "5778995a-e1bf-45b8-affa-663a9f3f4d04"
      type = "Scope"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please see if this helps: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39869024/permissions-required-to-list-azure-ad-groups. AFAIK, Group Read operations require administrator privileges.

Comment: The SP was granted the permissions and the admin consent was granted. But the post you reference implies that an additional permission is needed - "Read All Groups" which is contrary to the documentation. I will get it and retest, but if it works, that means the documentation is wrong.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please note that **Application permissions** are different from **Delegated permissions**. If you are using service principal to call the api, you should grant your application application permission.

[image]

Reference:

[Types of permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v1-permissions-and-consent#types-of-permissions)

Comment: I added the terraform code for creating the permissions. Am I correct in saying that I should use `Role` instead of `Scope` for all of them?

Comment: @mark If you are using service principal, the permissions you need are application permissions. And you should use `Role`.

Comment: Just so that I understand, I achieve this by changing `Scope` to `Role`, right? Or is there additional place? Sorry for asking too many questions, this API permissions model is currently klingonian to me.

Comment: @mark Based on the description you provided, it is yes. Also, remember to grant admin consent.

Comment: The bottom link is dead.

Answer (score 3):

Just add Api Permission "Azure Active Directory Graph" from Azure Active Directory-->App Registrations-->(Service Principal)-->Api Permissioins-->Add Permissions.

1. Application.ReadWrite.All
2. Directory.ReadWrite.All

[image]

Comment: ReadWrite.All is too permissive. The accepted answer lets me have the desired effect without opening my entire AAD for that service principal.

Comment: For Data loading, read permission is enough but for creating user from Azure DevOps Panel read.write permission is needed.

Comment: But not for All. I use Application.ReadWrite.OwnedBy

Comment: Note that 'Azure Active Directory Graph' has been marked as legacy from June 2020. Use similar permissions in 'Microsoft Graph' instead.